# Number of complex roots

Tags: complex-analysis

Find total number of roots inside $|z| \le 1$ for $\sin(z^{100})=z/11$.
I tried to apply Rouché's theorem:

> For any two complex-valued functions $f$ and $g$ holomorphic inside some region $K$ with closed contour $\partial K$ if $|g(z)| < |f(z)|$ on $\partial K$ then $f$ and $f + g$ have the same number of zeros inside $K$.

Also, $\sin(z^{100})=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(z^{100})^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\cdot(-1)^n$

However, it gets me nowhere. Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: If I remember correctly, if a power series have infinitely many roots inside a compact, then it's the null power series.

Comment: Why do you have $4n+2$ in your expansion? It seems it should be $2n+1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a hassle to find the values of $\sin(z^{100})$ on $|z|=1$, but since $z^{100}$ and $z$ take on the same values on $|z|=1$, let's just see the modulus of $\sin(z)$ on the unit circle. The range of moduli $\sin(z)$ takes on is the same as the range of moduli $\sin(z^{100})$ takes on. (only for $|z|=1$.

We have $$\sin(x+iy)=\sin(x)\cosh(y)+i\cos(x)\sinh(y)$$ the modulus of which is $$\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\sin^2(x)(e^{2y}+2+e^{-2y})+\cos^2(x)(e^{2y}-2+e^{-2y})}$$$$=\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{e^{2y}+e^{-2y}+2\sin^2(x)-2\cos^2(x)}$$ $$\displaystyle =\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(e^{2y}-4+e^{-2y})+(4-2\cos(2x))}$$

$$\geq \displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

On the unit circle, where $-1 \leq y \leq 1$, this is greater than $\displaystyle \frac{1}{11}$, which is the modulus of $-\displaystyle \frac{z}{11}$ on $|z|=1$.

Now, by Rouché's Theorem, since $\sin(z^{100})$ has $100$ roots inside $|z|=1$ (counting multiplicity), and $\displaystyle \left|\sin\left(z^{100}\right)\right|>\left|-\frac{z}{11}\right|$ on $|z|=1$, we have that $\displaystyle \sin(z^{100})-\frac{z}{11}$ has $100$ roots inside $|z|=1$.

Note, that since the moduli of $\sin(z^{100})$ and $\displaystyle -\frac{z}{11}$ never attain the same modulus on $|z|=1$, there are no roots on there.

Comment: isn't the minimum value just sin(1)? nothing wrong with this though